# ASP.NET MVC 4 app with bundling and minification, why is minification enabled in debug mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I've just migrated an ASP.NET MVC 3 project to MVC 4 / .NET 4.0, and installed NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` in order to support bundling and minification of CSS and JavaScript. I've pretty much got bundling/minification working, the problem is it's *always* enabled. Even though the app is in debug mode, as configured in Web.config, all JavaScript includes are minified. As you can see from the below XML snippet, debug mode is enabled in Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    ...
  </compilation>
  ...
</system.web>
```

An excerpt of my bundle configuration:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        ...

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.form.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.format.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/Site.css"));

        ...
    }
}
```

CSS/JavaScript includes are rendered in the HTML as for example:

```
<link href="/content/css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/bundles/jquery" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why minification gets enabled in my case? I am at a loss as to what I'm missing here. To troubleshoot I created a test ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet application and could verify that CSS/JavaScript did *not* get minified in debug mode for this project.

**EDIT:**

In my _Layout.cshtml file I render the styles/scripts like this:

```
@Styles.Render("content/css")
@Scripts.Render("bundles/jquery")
```

Thanks to Hao, I realize that I've forgot to prefix the bundle names with "~/".

Comment: This question may be helpful. [How to disable Javascript/CSS minification in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373071/how-to-disable-javascript-css-minification-in-asp-net-mvc-4?rq=1)

Comment: @jrummell The answers to that question seem to be for unconditionally disabling minification? I just want the standard conditional minification to work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The red flag is with the link/script tags rendered in your HTML:

These should contain a version hashcode if you are using Script/Style.Render, i.e.

```
< script src="/bundles/jquery?v=wvLq7H7qEZB2giyIRn7aEZAxhHOb2RfTYYh2HMd9EqM1"/>
```

To get the debug/release behavior that the MVC4 templates are using, you must use the Script/Style.Render methods as well. When calling these methods, you must pass virtual bundle paths, in your example:

```
@Styles.Render("~/content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

In debug mode, you should not get link/script tags pointing at the bundle (which will always be minified/bundled).  Instead you should be getting script/link tags to the individual resources in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for that. But shouldn't @Scripts.Render(...) throw an exception if not given a virtual path? When would you want to write @Scripts.Render("/bundles/jquery") i.e. without the "~"?

Comment: Its not limited to bundle urls, they will render script/link tags to arbitrary urls (both relative and absolute) as well.  The idea longer term was for these helpers to handle asset managment in general as opposed to just be bundle specific helpers.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. But we wasted half a day today because someone had forgotten to put in the "~".

Comment: @HaoKung would you mind looking into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834384/asp-net-mvc-4-is-bundling-js-files-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 2):

I just had this happen on a brand new ASP.NET MVC project.  I had the `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />` set to true in web.config and was still getting minified output.

**The fix**

BundleConfig.cs (in App_Start) has a line at the bottom `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` which was overriding my web.config setting....

Remove the line and/or set it to false and I got my scripts as unminified/unbundled as desired in debug environment.

I recommend removing the line since this will override web.config.  Setting this in the web.config has the advantage of using web.config transforms so that you can create different settings for deploying to different environments.

For more information on this see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification and read the *Controlling Bundling and Minification section* (about half way down the article).

Comment: This was the issue for me it seems that the default template for BundleConfig.cs has changed somewhere over time. Im sure that never used to be in there